# Is it somehow possible to transfer date from a RadComboBox to another RadComboBox (Different Page)?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp-classic

I have 3 different  RadComboBoxs  in one page and the  3 RadComboboxes in another page is it somehow possible to transfer the selected values from the first three Comboboxes to the other Comboboxes (Maybe via URL Javascript ) ?

if you need my code just ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a start Try query string:

**in Page1.aspx**

in some button click event

```
Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?id1="+RadComboBox1.SelectedValue+"&id2="+RadComboBox2.SelectedValue)
```

and

**in Page2.aspx**

in page load event

```
string cmb1Value = Request.QueryString["id1"].ToString();
string cmb2Value = Request.QueryString["id2"].ToString();
```

and bind these values to required comboboxes here as below.

```
//Use RadComboBox.SelectedIndex
int index1 = RadComboBox1.FindItemIndexByValue(cmb1Value );
RadComboBox1.SelectedIndex = index1;

int index2 = RadComboBox2.FindItemIndexByValue(cmb2Value );
RadComboBox2.SelectedIndex = index2;
```

Comment: Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox' could be found if i use .SelectedValue then i got (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: .SelectedValue then i got (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: 2 code is there    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string cmb1Value = Request.QueryString["id1"].ToString();
            string cmb2Value = Request.QueryString["id2"].ToString();

Comment: sry it was my fault, but still it dont work there is maybe no error but there is also no result on the second page

Comment: what is the url you get in the second page,paste here

Comment: http://localhost/HolidayTracker/Report/MonthYearReport.aspx?id1=7&id2=8   i see that work but how can i get these selected values in the second  page RadComboBo

Comment: dont use RadComboBox.SelectedIndex      .SelectedValue is better  and it works